# Mvn build of Struts 6.3.0.2 project fails to deploy on tomcat10

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, struts2

I created a Struts2 project using maven archetype blank. When I execute mvn jetty:run, the app works fine. However, if I execute "mvn package" and manually deploy to Tomcat, the app fails to start. Dito if I try to deploy from within eclipse IDE with a Tomcat 10 in it. Prod target will be Tomcat.

It appears the struts2 filter is not being recognized. See the two trace below. Below is when I tried deployment in Tomcat using manager GUI.

```
05-Jan-2024 09:28:44.708 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-16] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-10.1.17\webapps\basic_struts-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war]
05-Jan-2024 09:28:46.598 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-16] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
05-Jan-2024 09:28:46.598 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-16] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
05-Jan-2024 09:28:46.598 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-16] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/basic_struts-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] startup failed due to previous errors
05-Jan-2024 09:28:46.613 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-16] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-10.1.17\webapps\basic_struts-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war] has finished in [1,905] ms
05-Jan-2024 09:28:52.532 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-20] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
05-Jan-2024 09:28:52.547 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-20] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
05-Jan-2024 09:28:52.547 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-20] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/basic_struts-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] startup failed due to previous errors
05-Jan-2024 09:30:35.159 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-22] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop The stop() method was called on component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/basic_struts-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]] after stop() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.
05-Jan-2024 09:30:35.703 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-22] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy Undeploying context [/basic_struts-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
```

**Second trace**

When working in Eclipse and targeting Tomcat deployment, the console message says struts2 filter failed to start. Below is the console message in Eclipse-

```
Jan 05, 2024 10:48:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.17]
Jan 05, 2024 10:48:17 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jan 05, 2024 10:48:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter [struts2]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1013)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2352)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:800)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:491)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:473)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4886)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:845)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:795)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: **javax.servlet.Filter**
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1353)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1165)
    ... 40 more

Jan 05, 2024 10:48:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
Jan 05, 2024 10:48:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/basic_struts] startup failed due to previous errors
Jan 05, 2024 10:48:17 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
```

Do you have any recommendations? Here is what I have tried --

1. I made sure the eclipse buildpath has the struts2 (6.3.0.2) libs on the classpath.
2. I added an entry to make sure the Struts2 lib under build classpath gets picked in Project/Properties/Deployment Assembly by adding an entry and seeing it being placed under WEB-INF/lib
3. I tried looking for a recent tomcat plugin for maven, but did not find any. The instructions for tomcat 8 maven plugin do not work.
4. None of the other Struts2 examples (on Github) that build and run under jetty, are able to run under Tomcat if I do mvn package and then try to manually deploy.

Here are my files --

**Web.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
      org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
    </filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>WEB-INF/index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**Struts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.5//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.5.dtd">
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false"/>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true"/>
    <include file="example.xml"/>
    <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
        <default-action-ref name="index"/>
        <action name="index">
            <result type="redirectAction">
                <param name="actionName">HelloWorld</param>
                <param name="namespace">/example</param>
            </result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

**HelloWorld.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title><s:text name="HelloWorld.message"/></title>
</head>

<body>
<h2><s:property value="message"/></h2>

<h3>Languages</h3>
<ul>
    <li>
        <s:url var="url" action="HelloWorld">
            <s:param name="request_locale">en</s:param>
            
        </s:url>
        <s:a href="%{url}">English</s:a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <s:url var="url" action="HelloWorld">
            <s:param name="request_locale">es</s:param>
        </s:url>
        <s:a href="%{url}">Espanol</s:a>
    </li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

**Action Class HelloWorld.java**

```
package basic_struts.example;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

/**
 * <code>Set welcome message.</code>
 */
public class HelloWorld extends ActionSupport {

    public String execute() throws Exception {
        setMessage(getText(MESSAGE));
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    /**
     * Provide default value for Message property.
     */
  public static final String MESSAGE = "HelloWorld.message";
   // public static final String MESSAGE = "My Test Message";

    /**
     * Field for Message property.
     */
    private String message;

    /**
     * Return Message property.
     *
     * @return Message property
     */
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    /**
     * Set Message property.
     *
     * @param message Text to display on HelloWorld page.
     */
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Comment: *javax* is removed from Tomcat 10, but you still use Struts 6.x is the 6.x series of the Apache Struts framework has a minimum requirement of the following specification versions: Servlet API 3.1, JSP API 2.1, and Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

Go back to Tomcat 9. Tomcat 10.1 uses Jakarta EE 9, meaning the "jakarta" package names, not the original "javax" package names--this is why you get a runtime error about the Filter type. Until there is a newer Struts release targeting Jakarta EE 9 or higher, you can not use Tomcat 10.1.

Comment: I tried it. Appreciate the pointer, thank you!